# Service Layer between BLL and Presentation Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have a question about the service layer in an ASP.NET MVC application.

In the service layer, there are only DTO's and the DI for the business and data access layer. In the service layer I map the DTOs to the domain model. That means, I define the DTO classes in the service layer and then map it to EF entities and send this to the business layer. Is that correct?

I don't understand how I call the methods from the business layer in the mvc application. I think that in the business layer I have to define the CreateUser() method or anything else. All of my processes takes place in the business layer. Does the service layer also have a CreateUser() method, which I call from the presentation layer?

I think, I don't really understand how this service layer will be implemented, but I think it's good to implement it, because it facade the BLL and DAL from the presentation layer.

Thanks
Dominik

Comment: More about layers: http://tinyurl.com/d99w8rl

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you very much! But one question remains. The service layer implementation is only dispatching commands that can called from the presentation layer to the application layer. Is it really so easy?

Comment: All the logic is in the application layer, the service layer is only exposing it.